# How to print array element which is returned from function as a pointer?

Tags: c

I want to print month name which is an array element (return from function as a pointer..)

This is my function:

```
/*I have taken this from book by Dennis Ritchie*/
/* month name : return name of n-th month */
char *month_name(int n){
     static char *name[] = {
     "illegal month","January","February","March","April","May","June","July",
     "August","September","October","November","December"};
return (n < 1 || n > 12) ? name[0] : name[n];
}
```

Now I am unable to collect this pointer in my `main()` function. I have tried this way

```
void main(void)
{
 int k = 0, i = 0;
 char *s;
 printf("Enter month number\n");
 scanf("%d",&k);

 s = month_name(k);
 for(i = 0; *(s+i) != '/0'; i++)
      printf("%c",*(s+i));
 getch();
}
```

Comment: You've got any issues with `puts(month_name(k))`?

Comment: Typo: `'/0'` should be `'\0'`

Comment: In your `for` loop: `'/0'` should be `'\0'`

Comment: I'm surprised your compiler didn't warn you about that. GCC says **warning: multi-character character constant**

Comment: sorry frnds....  I got the output..                                                                          @Barmar & Dmitri  .... it was typing mistake..

Comment: Lesson learned: Always take your compiler's warnings seriously.

Answer (score 2):

The reason why it is not working is because the following is incorrect

```
for ( i = 0; *(s+i) != '/0'; i++)
```

What you are trying to achieve in reality is to stop at null terminator. However! The null terminator in your code is incorrect.

Please change to the following:

```
for ( i = 0; *(s+i) != '\0'; i++)
```

> Null terminator = '\0'. You wrote '/0'.

Answer (score 1):

You can correct the null-typo, as others already suggested.

However, if you don't mind an alternate approach, as your function is returning a *string*, you can use the `%s` format specifier to print that directly, like

```
 printf("Month is %s\n", month_name(k));
```

Alternatively, as you're going to *print* a string directly, you can also write

```
  puts(month_name(k)));
```

Please note, `void main(void)` is not a valid signature for `main()`, as mandated by the standard. You should be using `int main(void)` instead.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use:

```
int main(void)
{
   int k = 0, i = 0;
   char *s;
   printf("Enter month number\n");
   scanf("%d",&k);

   printf("%s\n", month_name(k));

   return 0;
}
```

If you simply want to correct your code:

```
 for(i = 0; *(s+i) != '\0'; i++)
      printf("%c",*(s+i));
```

As you can see null termination is `'\0'` not `'/0'`